# NVidia X Server Settings GUI doesn't start on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, nvidia-settings

So, I have a problem with starting Nvidia X Server Setting. Running `nvidia-settings` also cause error like this:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

My system is: `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`
Drivers are properly installed `nvidia-smi:`

```
Fri Dec  7 16:00:11 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 415.18       Driver Version: 415.18       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   33C    P8    13W / 250W |     19MiB / 11177MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1183      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            16MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can change profile with `prime-select` from `nvidia` to `intel` but it takes no effect

```
~$prime-select query
nvidia
```

More over, I can install CUDA 10.0 and CuDNN and TensorFlow-GPU with Keras-GPU on top and it's working perfectly well. The only problem is: how to access Nvidia settings.

I've been trying to install OpenJVM versions 8.0 and 10.0, with same effect.

Drivers from PPA repository.

`ubuntu-drivers devices`

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001B06sv00001458sd00003752bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I've read related topics, but people also have problem with driver.
I reinstalled drivers couple times, but in vain.
Any thoughts?

Comment: We have same problem, fresh 18.04 install; dual RTX TITANs, 418 + CUDA 10.1 installed, nvidia-settings fails to launch.  Drivers are loading, CUDA is working.