# "Bricked" my Nvidia driver with newer kernels

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, kernel

This needs a bit of backstory, so I get right to it.

Earlier this evening I was running kernel 4.19.9 with Nvidia driver 410 present. Note I could not use it, I have (had) the same problem as this guy: [NVidia X Server Settings GUI doesn't start on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099198/nvidia-x-server-settings-gui-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu-18-04)

However, there was a Nvidia update, and for the first time I could get an error code when I put `nvidia-settings` into terminal. My search for that error got me to this page: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/9a88po/linux_mint_19_nvidia_prime_no_more_screentearing_3/

The tinkerer that I am, I changed my `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_osi="` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1` updated grub and rebooted.

To make long story short, I had a hard freeze before GUI could load. I managed to revert to kernel 4.15.0 and change grub command back to `nomodeset`.

Now at kernel 4.15 the Nvidia drivers don't show at all. No matter how much I purge and install again. And to make matters worse, IF I dare to move to kernel 4.19.9 (or any of the 4.19 kernels) and install Nvidia drivers, I get a hard freeze when rebooting.

I am not sure if I am ready to do `sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'` because I have read that it removes `nvidia-common` package.

I personally rather run on kernel 4.19.9, but I would also like to be able to install Nvidia drivers without the system freezing.

Is there any way to get this to work, or am I doomed to reinstall again??

All the best, and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing Linux Mint (really like their GUI). Now I can run kernel 4.19.9 and have Nvidia drivers + Cuda installed without freezes (just like on Ubuntu before my ventures).

So my solution this time was to reinstall.