# Not sure if I have a Nvidia-driver-410 bug or an error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am currently having a "small" problem getting my Nvidia drivers to work. It is identical to this post: [NVidia X Server Settings GUI doesn't start on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099198/nvidia-x-server-settings-gui-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I however have not installed CuDNN and TensorFlow-GPU.

```
$ uname -a
Linux OVG-HP 4.19.9-041909-generic #201812130432 SMP Thu Dec 13 
09:34:53 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The error/bug:

```
$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:9737): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:50:05.392: 
g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:9737): WARNING **: 21:50:05.394: PRIME: Failed to 
execute child process “/usr/bin/prime-supported” (No such file or 
directory)
** Message: 21:50:05.394: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I also tried to do `nvidia-xconfig`:

```
$ nvidia-xconfig

WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.


WARNING: Unable to parse X.Org version string.

Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-server.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-server' found

ERROR: Unable to write to directory '/etc/X11'.
```

Seems to me that I am missing "bunch" of files to run Nvidia driver, even if this is a fresh install of it (was just reinstalling). I have tried searching around for this behaviour but haven't really found much that helps.

Could this be caused of `nomodeset` in my grub? I noticed that I am also missing some folders from Intel, basically to control the screen brightness. I saw that happen from when I restarted after adding `nomodeset` to grub. The computer however won't run unless it has `nomodeset`.

If this is a bug, I will do my best to report it to developers. If not, all help is welcome. :)

Comment: Where did you install that Kernel from?  What version of Ubuntu are you running?  Was there a problem with the kernel that comes with the version of Ubuntu you are running?  There is a chance that the driver or nvidia-settings may not work with an unsupported kernel version.

Comment: I installed it with ukuu. There was nothing "wrong" with the 4.15 kernel, but the difference is that the computer runs colder now (much less ramping up fans). I had the this problem on Ubuntu 18.04 and after my newest reinstall I use Linux Mint 19 (which is a derivative of Ubuntu 18.04). I had EXACT same problem in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Since the Kernel is not a version that is currently supported in the stable releases I would recommend that you file a bug against the driver or the nvidia-settings app for that specific kernel.

Comment: Well, I do get exact same results on kernel 4.15 (might have put that better in my question) as on kernel 4.19.9.  I have the drivers installed but there seem like there are "bunch" of files missing.

Comment: I found the same problem over here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087714/18-10-unable-to-fully-install-nvidia-drivers-libnvidia-gl-xxx-libnvidia-gl-xx  I had to dig pretty much to find it.

Comment: Sorry it has taken me a while, but I wonder if you run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` to create a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file if that will help it so that the `nvidia-settings` work then?

Comment: Running `sudo nvidia-xconfig` creates `xorg.conf` and `xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-orginal` file, but I still have the same problem when running `nvidia-settings`. It results in `(nvidia-settings:5247): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 08:50:44.395: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 08:50:44.397: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 08:50:44.397: PRIME: is it supported? no
`

Comment: Going through synaptic package manager, it says that `libnvidia-ifr1-410` package is broken and therefore I can't install `libnvidia-gl-410` properly.

Comment: I have found that when you have broken packages like that you have to remove / uninstall the driver package and reinstall it.   You cannot just install over it.  That actual error message you are seeing there is exactly what I see, so it is of no help unfortunately.  I would at this point say to go ahead and file a bug report on nvidia-settings.

Comment: @Terrance Alright, I will figure out how to do that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The command should just simply be `ubuntu-bug nvidia-settings`

Comment: @Terrance I get a small problem `Problem in nvidia-settings, It is not possible to reprort the bug. This is not an official Linux package. Please remove any third party package and try again`. It is roughly what it says, have to translate from my native language.

Comment: Did you install the NVIDIA drivers from NVIDIA themselves?  If so, I would then say to go ahead and remove the drivers then install from the PPA like in https://askubuntu.com/a/1070682/231142 but you should be able to install from 390 all the way up to 415.  Yeah, unfortunately I cannot file a bug on the same application.  Looks like that bug will have to be file through NVIDIA themselves.

Comment: @Terrance I installed Nvidia drivers through ppa. So we need to go through Nvidia. Bit of a bummer to buy a machine to game on and not being able to game :D

Comment: You should still be able to game.  Even though the nvidia-settings may not be coming up, you can still manually set the settings in the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.  There is a lot of documentation out there on settings that you can configure.  In all honesty, I hardly ever use the `nvidia-settings` and do all my configurations just in the `xorg.conf` file.

Comment: https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/1.0-8762/README/appendix-d.html

Comment: I shoudl have said graphic heavy games. I have had bit of crashes tinkering with files I shouldn't be tinkering with :D I just want to get my GTX 1050 to start doing its thing

Comment: I understand that is what you want.  Unfortunately, Linux in general is not good yet for games with heavy graphics.  Most of those games are suited for Windows.  It does make me sad.  However, they are always working more and more to make games work better with Linux as Wine is constantly under development and getting better.  With Steam there are games that will now work great under Linux and they are still developing Proton for all games to work.  I have set it up and it seemed to work OK, but still had some glitches and some games just did not work.  It is all hit and miss.

Comment: Proton works great with my Ryzen APU, and I am super exited for that program. I prefer Linux over Windows. Is Linux perfect? No, but neither is Windows, and I like to learn about my OS when I run into problem :) I am less annoyed to install Linux up again over Windows. Anyway, we are way off topic. Merry Christmas from over here (or happy holiday depending of what you prefer).

Comment: Keep up the learning!  I wish that I was more help on this one!  I agree with you about preferring Linux over Windows.  =)  Merry Christmas to you!  =)